# Multiple xAxis on Highcharts

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

[image: I am trying to implement attached chart using Highcharts. I have been able to plot bars with Lines on my chart. But I am unable to plot multiple xAxis with Dates and Group by Months. has any one implemented such chart. Please help]

I am trying to implement attached chart using Highcharts. I have been able to plot bars with Lines on my chart. But I am unable to plot multiple xAxis with Dates and Group by Months. has any one implemented such chart. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can use two xAxes, just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/21g0hfo1/1/

```
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat("%e", this.value);
            }
        }
    }, {
        linkedTo: 0,
        type: 'datetime',
        tickLength: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %e", this.value);
            }
        }
    }],
```

I just connected second xAxis to the first one and each of them has different label formatter.

Comment: Somewhat, thats what I want. But do you know how can I get month for the starting series. In your fiddler, there is no month before Jan, thats because of the tickInterval. Any work around to show previous month?

Comment: Feel free to post your example :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want multiple xAxis but rather a tick label formatter that'll change the label for the start of each month:

```
var lastMonth = null;    
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime', 
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var thisMonth = Highcharts.dateFormat("%b", this.value);
                if (lastMonth != thisMonth){
                    lastMonth = thisMonth;
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %e", this.value);
                } else {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat("%e", this.value);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ....
```

Produces an axis like this (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/21g0hfo1/)):

[image]

Comment: I have already tried that with formatter. But my requirement is little different. I want my dates to be grouped by Months. Both dates and months need to be displayed separately like shown in the screenshot.